# MS Graph API - Setting Out of Office replies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to develop a Microsoft Graph based application. Trying to set OOF (Out of Office) messages using Delegated permission. I made sure that i have MailboxSettings.ReadWrite permission set. I tried calling PATCH, but it doesnt give any errors and also it's not updating the OOF update request in mailbox settings as well. Any pointers/sample would be of help.

Comment: I tried the below with MS Graph explorer and POSTMAN - it works for me!!

 PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Me/mailboxSettings",
    "automaticRepliesSetting": {
        "status": "Scheduled",
        "scheduledStartDateTime": {
          "dateTime": "2020-03-20T18:00:00.0000000",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "scheduledEndDateTime": {
          "dateTime": "2020-03-28T18:00:00.0000000",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Also you can refer the documentation as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings

Comment: Wow what a faster response. Yay, the above sample works. Appreciate your assistance Dev!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below payload with MS Graph explorer &  POSTMAN - it works for me!!

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings 
Content-Type: application/json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Me/mailboxSettings",
"automaticRepliesSetting": {
    "status": "Scheduled",
    "scheduledStartDateTime": {
      "dateTime": "2020-03-20T18:00:00.0000000",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "scheduledEndDateTime": {
      "dateTime": "2020-03-28T18:00:00.0000000",
      "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
}
```

You can refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings) as well.